# GET data with Google+ share button

Tags: url, button, get, google-plus, share

I want to use the Google+ share button in a HTML email. I put the hyperlink

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url={URL}
```

into the email.

But when I try the hyperlink there is a problem with the GET-data. If I put `?parameter=name` into the URL, Google+ doesn't take it.

How can I send the right URL?

Comment: Please clarify the problem (include error text, full response, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Per the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/#sharelink), the `url` value must be url encoded.

E.g. `http://example.com/?foo=bar` should be `http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Ffoo%3Dbar`

```
https://plus.google.com/share?url=http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F%3Ffoo%3Dbar
```

In JavaScript you can use `encodeURIComponent('http://example.com/?foo=bar')`